# How to return an unmodifiable map from Collectors.groupingBy in java?

Tags: java, java-stream

So I have a map that takes a Long as a key and a list as a value.
I want both the map and the list in each entry to be unmodifiable.

```java
Map<Long, List<VariantValueDto>> variantValues = productVariantValues.stream()
    .map(p -> new VariantValueDto(
        p.getProductVariantId(), p.getOptionId(), p.getOptionName(), p.getOptionValueId(), p.getValueName()
    ))
    .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(VariantValueDto::getProductVariantId));
```

how to return such results?

Comment: Use Collections.unmodifiableMap(variantValues); to create a new unmodifiable map without copying the entire thing

Answer (score 10, accepted):

For the unmodifiable list, [`groupingBy`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/stream/Collectors.html#groupingBy(java.util.function.Function,java.util.stream.Collector)) takes a collector as an optional 2nd argument, so you can pass [`Collectors.toUnmodifiableList()`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/stream/Collectors.html#toUnmodifiableList()), rather than the implicit default `toList()`.

For the unmodifiable map, there is a function [`collectingAndThen`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/stream/Collectors.html#collectingAndThen(java.util.stream.Collector,java.util.function.Function)) which takes a collector and a function to be applied at the end, and returns a new collector. So you can wrap the `groupingBy` in that and call `unmodifiableMap` on it.

```
Map<Long, List<VariantValueDto>> variantValues = productVariantValues.stream()
    .map(p -> new VariantValueDto(...))
    .collect(
        Collectors.collectingAndThen(
            Collectors.groupingBy(
                VariantValueDto::getProductVariantId,
                Collectors.toUnmodifiableList()
            ),
            Collections::unmodifiableMap
         )
    );
```

Comment: thanks, this API is full of features to learn

Comment: It's worth noting that the methods `toUnmodifiable...()` were introduced in Java 10 and you do _not_ have to use `collectingAndThen(..)` at all if you're using Java 10+. OTOH, you can only use `collectingAndThen(..)` if you're using Java 8/9. This is applicable to lists, sets, and maps.